# VBA class performance

Tags: vba

I've got this code:

```
For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
    Set qc = qcolumns(i)
    If qc.XlGrouped = True Then
...
```

What is weird for me is that if I change `qc.XlGrouped = True` to `qcolumns(i).XlGrouped = True` it will take 200ms while the first one takes 0ms. Why such a difference just from setting class from an array to a variable?

Comment: I would imagine that `qcolumns(i).XlGrouped` has to extract the class from the array and then do the property check, where the 1st is just the property check.

Comment: It's weird because if you set it to variable is much much faster. So I don't get it why this "extraction" would take this much. Unless it's duplicating it and setting to a variable just sets a reference.

Comment: How are `qc` and `qcolumns()` defined, and where is the code in the VBA project? Is it in class, a module, a worksheet? We need to see the `Dim` statements so we know what is what.

Comment: `Dim qcolumns As Variant` ; `Dim qc As settingscolumns` ; `qcolumns` in an array of custom classes, `qc` is is a custom class.

Comment: Have you tried alternative collection objects to use instead of array, the collection or the dictionary, see how they perform?  Looking at your dim's, this method `qcolumns(i).` would also need time to find a suitable object to put it in.  It is unusual the amount of time I imagine.

Comment: `qcolumns` array has 4 positions... so that's not a problem. I'll try collection. That might work faster.

Comment: Ok I tried collection but it's actually even slower than array.

Comment: You tried a collection, but were you iterating it with a `For` loop or a `For Each` loop? It makes [quite a massive difference](https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/)

Comment: I was doing for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 200ms is anecdotal, but the overhead can be explained.

```
Dim qcolumns As Variant
```

That's your array, but to VBA it's just a `Variant`: in order to know it's looking at an array, VBA needs (at runtime) to dereference the variant pointer, inspect the bytes that hold the subtype metadata, get the array pointer, ...and dereference the array pointer.

There would be less overhead with an explicit array declaration:

```
Dim qcolumns(1 To 10) As SettingsColumns
```

Now, we don't really care about the array... we're just trying to iterate its contents:

```
Set qc = qcolumns(i)
```

So at each iteration, the variant/array dereferencing needs to happen, and the object pointer gets copied to `qc`. But why is it slower to make a member call against `qcolumns(i)`?

Because `qcolumns` is a `Variant`, any member call made against it has to be late-bound, i.e. resolved at run-time. The `XlGrouped` property isn't known to VBA until the member call succeeds, and the member call can only succeed after querying the `IUnknown` interface of the object (if that fails, error 438 is raised).

When you do `Dim qc As SettingsColumn`, you are binding early, at compile-time. Now the compiler already knows where to find the `XlGrouped` member, and doesn't need to query `IUnknown` through a `Variant` pointer: everything is much simpler... and usually simpler means faster.

But you're iterating an array of objects: that's going to be slower than it needs to be, no matter what.

Objects want to be iterated in a `Collection`, using a `For Each` loop.

```
Dim qc As SettingsColumn
For Each qc In myCollection
    If qc.XlGrouped Then  '<~ note =True is redundant
       '...
    End If
Next
```

See [For vs For Each](https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/) for more information and performance benchmarks. The bottom line is, iterating an object `Collection` with a `For` loop and retrieving each item by index, is always going to be much slower than a `For Each` loop; use `For` to iterate arrays of values, `For Each` to iterate collections of objects.

Comment: I see, so if I do `set qc = qcolumns(i)` the pointer gets precompiled? While looping of an array doesn't and it then needs to find a memory location for it each time? (sorry for newbish question)

Comment: No. When you do `qcolumns(i).MemberCall`, the member call is late-bound, because all the compiler sees is a `Variant`. When you do `Set qc = qcolumns(i)`, if `qc` is declared `As Variant` then `qc.MemberCall` is still late bound. What makes it early bound is `Dim qc As SettingsColumn`. That's a separate issue from how the data structure (array vs collection) is being iterated and how each item is retrieved (by index vs by enumerator).

Comment: @DamGal actually, kinda - the dereferencing needs to occur at every iteration. If the array contains numbers or strings (i.e. plain values), a `For` loop is extremely fast. It's slower when objects are involved, and `For Each` is optimized for iterating object collections, so think values=>array=>for and objects=>collection=>for each =)